# EF4 Eager Loading from nested and shared tables

Tags: entity-framework-4, eager-loading

In my database I have a `Company`. The company has `Branches`, which have an `Address`. The company also has `Accounts`, which have `ReturnAddresses`, which also have an `Address`.

I want to eager load all this data in one query, something like:

```
from c in context.Company  
           .Include("Branches").Include("Address")
           .Include("Accounts").Include("ReturnAddresses").Include("Address")
where c.CompanyId.Equals(1)    
select c
```

Will the two `.Include("Address")` methods figure themselves to get the right addresses for the right aspects?

How else can I load all this data in one query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In EF 4.1 you can do so as follows

```
from c in context.Company  
  .Include(c => c.Branches.Select(b => b.Address))
  .Include(c => c.Accounts.Select(a => a.ReturnAddresses.Select(r => r.Address)))
where c.CompanyId.Equals(1)    
select c
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a dot notation like you do on a navigation property so:

```
Include("Entity.Property")
```